# phpMyAdmin - Cookie Encryption - How to use in third-party code

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to use the same cookie encryption that phpMyAdmin does because I am making a custom cPanel for a hosting server, and I am unable to get the cookie data to look the same. I already have the cookie pmaUser-1 and pmaAuth-1 added but the cookie (using the same blowfish_secret) on mine is about 30 characters shorter and doesnt include % signs.

Whats the proper function to encrypt this cookie value to be the same as phpMyAdmins?

This is the current code I am using the encrypt my cookie

```
    $pmadbu = crypt($pmadbu, $config_secretkey);
    $pmadbp = crypt($pmadbp, $config_secretkey);
    setcookie("pmaUser-1", $pmadbu);
    setcookie("pmaAuth-1", $pmadbp);
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is opensource, download and read the code

Comment: I am looking through the code but i cannot find where they are encrypting the username and password or I would just copy their function..

Comment: If you simply read the doc page on [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) you'd see that right in the description it says: "crypt — One-way string hashing" *not encryption*.

Comment: Have you looked at the 'signon' auth_type which may do exactly what you want?